# LTTng live view with port forwarding / tunneling

Tags: trace, portforwarding, lttng

I have a PC **A** where LTTng tracing is running with live view

```sh
lttng create trace-session --live

# Traces will be output to tcp4://127.0.0.1:5342/ [data: 5343]
```

Another PC **B** is directly connected with **A** with a Ethernet cable. At the same time, **B** is connected to a local network.

Now how can I view the live trace events from a third PC **C**, which is in the same local network as **B**, for example with

```
babeltrace2 "net://${B_IP}/host/${B_HOSTNAME}/trace-session"
```

I ran the following command on PC **C**, to make a tunnel to PC **A*.

```sh
ssh -L 5342:${A_IP}:5342 -N user_name@${B_IP}
```

However, it seems not to have worked. I would like to ask:

- What have I done wrong here?
- What is the standard way to "forward" LTTng live tracing events to be viewed by `babeltrace2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Babeltrace2` connects to `lttng-relayd` using the `live` port  of the `lttng-relayd` process not the data and control ports.

When the command line report the following:

```
# Traces will be output to tcp4://127.0.0.1:5342/ [data: 5343]
```

It means that the `lttng-sessiond` and `lttng-consumerd` process will communicate with a `lttng-relayd` process listening on the `127.0.0.1:5342` for control message and `127.0.0.1:5343` for trace data exchange. A viewer, in this case `Babeltrace2` can connect to the `live` port of a `lttng-relayd` process to stream live session. You can take a deeper look at the component graph [here](https://lttng.org/docs/v2.12/#doc-plumbing).

The default live port is 5344 and the default behavior for the `lttng-relayd` process is to bind on all interfaces to listen. Naturally `Babeltrace2` also default on using that port if none is specified to communicate with the `lttng-relayd` process.

See the man page of [lttng-relayd](https://lttng.org/man/8/lttng-relayd/v2.12/) for more details.

> What have I done wrong here?

In your scenario you need to tunnel the 5344 port. Note that I'm not versed in ssh tunneling so I cannot validate the ssh approach here.

```
ssh -L 5344:${A_IP}:5344 -N user_name@${B_IP}
```

> What is the standard way to "forward" LTTng live tracing events to be viewed by babeltrace2?

`Babeltrace2` and `lttng-relayd` use TCP for communication. Hence, all TCP "forwarding" methods are acceptable here. As you probably noticed, LTTng does not encrypt communication and trace data in any way. I would say that using a ssh tunnel is appropriate here if you need to move data across non-trusted network.